# Override SASS variables in Middleman with Bower

Tags: sass, bower, middleman

## Solved!

This failure caused by Sass version.

In conclusion, can't be used Sass version 3.4.x with Foundation 5. Otherwise, we will recieved warning from terminal when type `compass compile` command and fail the compile.

We should use Bundler to avoid this.

If use Bundler, we can control Sass version per project. Great!

---

I'm trying to override variables of Foundation in Middleman with Bower.

Fast, I installed Foundation with bower.

```
bower install foundation
```

Foundation installed in `bower_components` directory.

Next, I writed below code in Middleman `config.rb` to import foundation resources in `all.sass`.

```
after_configuration do 
  sprockets.append_path "#{root}/bower_components/"
end
```

Finally, I found below article and I'm tried it.

http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/override-scss-variables/966/3

I written below code in `all.sass`

```
$font-family-sans-serif: Verdana, "游ゴシック", YuGothic, "Hiragino Kaku Gothic ProN", Meiryo, sans-serif
@import 'foundation'
```

Above code was not worked. Not changed font family in browser.

I would like to keep clean installed resources with Bower. Because probably deleted when I type `bower update` command.

Is there any good way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Sass are you using? Try adding the `!global` flag to the variable definition.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'm using SASS version 3.4.6 and tried it immediately. `$font-family-sans-serif: Verdana, "游ゴシック", YuGothic, "Hiragino Kaku Gothic ProN", Meiryo, sans-serif !global` The result did not change, but I did not know flag. Also I'll try to examine other flag.